# Scrapy: serializing item data which is not item class item

Tags: python, scrapy

Each product is associated with a large number of price pages for which I do not wish to create an individual item. Instead Id like to aggregate the data into a single field, e.g. avgerage-price for each product.

At present, what happens below is the productprice field is overwritten each time. I.e. the productprice field is a list with a single item (last product price scraped)

Id like to keep each price for the product and aggregate this data once the item has returned.

```
parse_it(self, response):
    ....
    for path in links:
       yield Request(
         path,
         meta={
         'item': item_loader.load_item()
         },
          callback=self.parse_price_page,
          dont_filter=True
            )

parse_price_page(self, response):
    productname = response.meta['item']['productname']
    product_price= response.xpath("//table/tr/td/text()").extract()
    item_loader.add_value("productprice", product_price)  
    return item_loader.load_item()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't see you creating the ItemLoader in the `parse_price_page()`, but you are using it.

Second, there is an `ItemLoader.get_collected_values()` that you could use to read the last collected value, add it to the new one, and store.
This is an untested example from the top of my head, you should play with the approach until you get it right:

```
def parse_price_page(self, response):
    item_loader = ItemLoader(item=response.meta['item'])
    productname = item_loader.get_collected_values('productname')
    old_price = item_loader.get_collected_values('productprice')
    new_price = response.xpath("//table/tr/td/text()").extract()[0]
    item_loader.add_value("productprice", int(old_price)+int(new_price))
    return item_loader.load_item()
```

Comment: There is am itemloader rest assured.